# Waiting in the UI thread but the function to set end condition is called in the UI thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, callback

I have a function `foo` that is called in the UI thread. Inside it, I call `functionA` whose return value will determine whether I call `functionB` or not. Inside `functionA`, I call `funcFromAnotherProject` which actually runs in a worker thread. I need to wait for this to end before I can proceed with `functionC`.

```
void foo() {
    bool succeeded = functionA();
    if (succeeded) functionB();
}
bool functionA() {
    if (someCondition) {
        funcFromAnotherProject();
    }
    return functionC();
}
```

Fortunately, `funcFromAnotherProject` can accept a callback parameter so I can actually pass `functionC` as a callback so the order is preserved. However, if I do this, I won't be able to get `functionC`'s return value which I need in `foo`.

I then decided to do the following (the `bool` variable is actually a shared pointer to a class that wraps around a `HANDLE` but it's too complicated):

```
bool functionA() {
    bool finishedFuncFromAnotherProject = false;
    auto callback = [&finishedFuncFromAnotherProject](){
        finishedFuncFromAnotherProject = true;
    };
    if (someCondition) {
        funcFromAnotherProject(callback);
        waitUntilAboveFuncFinishes();
    }
    return functionC();
}
```

The problem with this is that I am calling wait in the UI thread and `funcFromAnotherProject` calls the callback in the UI thread as well. The callback is never called because the `wait` is blocking everything else.

Running `foo` in the worker thread will solve the above problem, however I need to block the UI thread until `functionB` finishes.

`funcFromAnotherProject` will always run in a worker thread so I can't change that. If it comes down to it, what I can do is add a flag for `funcFromAnotherProject` on whether it should run the callback in the UI thread or not. But since this is a utility in our program, I'd rather not touch it.

Is there another way to go about this? I feel like this should be very simple and I'm just overthinking things.

Comment: Make functionA take a callback. (I said functionB before, that was a mistake)

Comment: @immibis Thanks, but it doesn't address my problem with wanting to wait for funcFromAnotherProject to finish before calling functionC. Sorry if my explanation was unclear and confused you regarding my actual question.

Comment: If it's a library/utility, just let funcFromAnotherProject call the callback in the context of the worker thread and document it as such, together with a note that the callback must not block/wait.  If a user wants to interact with a UI thread, it's then up to the user to signal the UI thread state-machine appropriately so that neither the callback or the UI thread does not need to wait. Usually, this means some kind of slot/message inter-thread comms to fire a 'worker thread completed' event with a context parameter, but that should be the responsibility of the lib user, not the lib author.

Comment: @yushi Well inside `functionA` when it calls `funcFromAnotherProject` it can pass a callback that will call `functionC` when the callback runs, and also call the callback that `foo` passed to `functionC`. Now you're writing node.js in C++ of course...

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Thanks, I also thought of doing this but in the end decided not to touch funcFromAnotherProject.

Comment: @immibis It took me a while to understand (because my mind is in overthinking mode) but I finally restructured the code to work similarly as you've pointed out. Thanks! If you turn this into an answer, I'll accept it.